# "The server could not update. Check your API credentials and internet connection and try again." - Google Sheets API, service account error

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api, google-cloud-console

I'm currently building a website/platform following using this: https://forensic-architecture.org/investigation/timemap-for-cartographic-platforms. It works by reading a Google sheet I have, and I need to press an 'update' button in order for the sheets to be read. However, rather than it updating, I get the following: "The server could not update. Check your API credentials and internet connection and try again."

I'm unsure what's going wrong, as I've followed all the steps as needed for the Google Sheets api, as outlined in the link above. I also previously had this running with a different API key locally (which I since deleted). Now, I can't even get it to work locally, though previously there was no issue. The service account has permission on the Sheet itself. I've also tried setting the sheet to publicly available online with no change. I've checked the service account and key are correct about a million times, and have created a new project with whole new key etc so see if the issue was reproduced. I also tried making a new sheet (and granting a new key etc permission) but still get the same error.

The metrics panel for Sheets API tells me "google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetSpreadsheet" has an error rate of 100%. I'm well below my quota, and have billing enabled (two other reasons I keep seeing on Stack as possible reasons for similar errors), so I'm not sure that's the issue.

Below is also what I see in terminal when trying to run locally (rn switched to trying to fix this locally as this is the last step for me in making the platform live, and I'm wary of doing anything on my remote server that could end up causing problems elsewhere):

```
Enabling CORS in development...
Connected to {{My Google Sheet name}} (Google Google Sheet with ID {{Sheet ID}}).
===================
grant access to: {{my service account email}}
===================
Started on port 4040

GET /api/blueprints 200 46.784 ms - 1677

GET /api/update 404 452.498 ms - 115
```

The platform reads my service key credentials through my .env (which it seems to be doing fine going from what I see in terminal), and uses a config file to find the Google Sheets id (which again seems fine from above).

Please let me know if there's any extra info needed here; I'm pretty new to all of this, and so not necessarily aware when I'm relaying issues what is vital info and what is not.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to accurately reproduce your issue. Please do so, and edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I realised my Sheet was an xlsx on sheets, so saved as a sheet and started working. Unsure why it became an issue as had previously been using the same sheet with no problem but hey ho!